# App Sevice on azure is down. Multiple errors which don't make sense to me

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Out of the blue my App service (asp.net core app) is down and nothing helps (e.g. restarting). Not my field of knowledge I have to say. Few noticeable things:

- First it throwed 502.
- Cannot even access kudu (advanced tools) on https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/ (also 502)
- In **Diagnose and solve problems** and **Web App Restarted** I have found this:
  [image]
- In **Diagnose and solve problems** and **Web App Down** I have found:

```
2021-10-04T21:19:50.239475918Z Failed to get size of file [/home/site/wwwroot/BlazorApp.Server.deps.json]
2021-10-04T21:19:50.239515518Z Error initializing the dependency resolver: An error occurred while parsing: /home/site/wwwroot/BlazorApp.Server.deps.json
```

And also this console output:

```
2021-10-04T20:42:04.875817259Z Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8080 -userStartupCommand 'dotnet BlazorApp.Server.dll' 
2021-10-04T20:42:04.934145638Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2021-10-04T20:42:04.941038071Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2021-10-04T20:42:04.941048571Z Build Operation ID: 1728b184-ac6f-47b3-a5fa-2ca5f55543ac
2021-10-04T20:42:12.944327812Z 
2021-10-04T20:42:12.944356612Z Agent extension 
2021-10-04T20:42:19.058804845Z Before if loop >> DotNet Runtime Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2021-10-04T20:42:25.687081462Z Running user provided startup command...
2021-10-04T20:43:02.238418373Z Failed to get size of file [/home/site/wwwroot/BlazorApp.Server.deps.json]
2021-10-04T20:43:02.238447773Z Error initializing the dependency resolver: An error occurred while parsing: /home/site/wwwroot/BlazorApp.Server.deps.json
```

[image]

Well, thank you for any help you provide!

Edit:
It is located in North Europe. Pay-as-you-go is my subscription. Graph about container crashes is added to the question.

Edit2:
The issue solved by itself after few hour. Is it possible to be related to that facebook outage?

Comment: Just to confirm, is your WebApp hosted in Canada Central region? Are you still experiencing this issue? What Azure subscription are you using? Does this issue occur on all the WebApps on the subscription or just this one?

Comment: Q update. I have just this app. I also tried to create new one on the same subscription while the first was down and it resulted in similar issues... The SO isn't probably the best place to solve this issues immediately , is there any better place?

Comment: Firstly, apologies for the inconvenience with this issue. Glad to know the issue was resolved. Thanks for the update. 
To update the community (adding from your comments), the issue was self-resolved after an hour. You typically would review the Azure Service Health for any reported issues on your subscription. 

You may post your question on Microsoft Q&A forum to receive swift help on such issues from our Microsoft SMEs/MVPs and the Q&A community or file a support ticket for urgent help.  Microsoft Q&: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/

Comment: Additionally more info: Azure Service Health provides personalized alerts and guidance when Azure service issues affect you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-health/service-health-overview 

Azure Resource Health helps you diagnose and get support for service problems that affect your Azure resources. It reports on the current and past health of your resources.
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-health/resource-health-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To benefit the community posting our discussion from comments section.
"The issue solved by itself after few hour."

Firstly, apologies for the inconvenience with this issue. Glad to know the issue was resolved. Thanks for the update.
Review the **Azure Service Health** for any reported issues on your subscription.

Also, review Azure Resource Health and Azure Status.

[Azure Service Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-health/service-health-overview) provides personalized alerts and guidance when Azure service issues affect you. It can notify you, help you understand the impact of issues, and keep you updated as the issue resolves. It can also help you prepare for planned maintenance and changes that could affect the availability of your resources.

[Azure Resource Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/service-health/resource-health-overview) helps you diagnose and get support for service problems that affect your Azure resources. It reports on the current and past health of your resources.

[Azure status](https://status.azure.com/status/history/) page is a global view of the health of all Azure services in all regions. Reports on service problems that affect a broad set of Azure customers.

You may post your question on Microsoft Q&A forum to receive swift help on such issues from our Microsoft SMEs/MVPs and the [Microsoft Q&A community](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/) or file a [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for any urgent help.

Thanks for your patience.